# Make alt key work when using NX client on OSX to Ubuntu 10.04 host?

Tags: macos, keyboard, xorg, nx

I am using NX Client on Mac OS X 10.6 to access my Ubuntu 10.04 machine.  I would like to use the Option/Alt key to Alt-Tab in the window manager and as the Meta key in Emacs.

Some searching on the internet suggests that I set my OSX ~/.Xmodmap file to:

```
keycode 66 = Alt_L
clear Mod1
add Mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R
```

Or:

```
clear Mod1
clear Mod2
keycode 63 = Mode_switch
keycode 66 = Meta_L
add Mod1 = Meta_L
add Mod2 = Mode_switch
```

Neither did the trick.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that Mac OS X captures some of the necessary key commands.  This seems to be a change from before.  Anyway, I stopped trying to do this and installed ubuntu on a separate partition on my mac.  Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the instruction #3 and Rich's comment on this blog post.
http://www.edwardotis.net/tech/?p=224